# Simplify an AST/LinkedList expression

Tags: java, recursion, abstract-syntax-tree, simplify

I'm working on a method that will simplify and AST expression. However, my AST tree structures like this:

For example, `5 + 6 * sin(y)`

Instead of having two links to left and right children nodes, the parent nodes will have a link to a list that contains their children. Therefore, the above example is like this :

```
Parent:[+] Children [5, \*], Parent:[\*] Children [6,sin()], Parent:[sin()] Children [y]
```

My code have successfully simplified expressions that contain only numbers or numbers and variables that have been assigned. However, it does not simplify expressions that contain both numbers and undefined variables.
I store defined variables in a Map
Whenever I enter something like `(1+1)*(2+4*(1+1))` or `1 + a + b` where `a` and `b` are defined I get correct answer. However, when variables are not defined, my simplify() method fails.

For example, an expression `1 + 1 + a + 2 * 4`. When calling simplify(), the expected results are something like `2 + a + 8` or `a + 10`, but the actual result that I get is simply `1 + 1 + a + 2 * 4`. Simplify() does not simplify at all. Can anybody suggest a way to improve my code that will deal with undefined variables case? Any helps are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
private static AstNode simplifyHelper(IDictionary<String, AstNode> variables, AstNode node) {
        if (node.isNumber()) {
            return node;
        } else if (node.isVariable()) {
            if (!variables.containsKey(node.getName())) {
                return node;
            } else {
                return simplifyHelper(variables, variables.get(node.getName()));
            }
        } else {
            String name = node.getName();

            AstNode one = simplifyHelper(variables, node.getChildren().get(0));
            AstNode two = null;
            if (node.getChildren().size() > 1) {
                two = simplifyHelper(variables, node.getChildren().get(1));
            }

            if (one.isNumber() && (two != null ? two.isNumber() : true)) {
                if (name.equals("+")) {
                    node = new AstNode(one.getNumericValue() + two.getNumericValue());
                } else if (name.equals("-")) {
                    node = new AstNode(one.getNumericValue() - two.getNumericValue());
                } else if (name.equals("*")) {
                    node = new AstNode(one.getNumericValue() * two.getNumericValue());
                } else if (name.equals("^")) {
                    node = new AstNode(Math.pow(one.getNumericValue(), two.getNumericValue()));
                } else if (name.equals("negate")) {
                    node = new AstNode(-one.getNumericValue());
                } else if (name.equals("sin")) {
                    node.getChildren().set(0, new AstNode(one.getNumericValue()));
                } else if (name.equals("cos")) {
                    node.getChildren().set(0, new AstNode(one.getNumericValue()));
                } else if (name.equals("/")) {
                    node.getChildren().set(0, new AstNode(one.getNumericValue()));
                    node.getChildren().set(1, new AstNode(two.getNumericValue()));
                }
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: Start by writing down the algebra equations you want to implement (e.g,,  " x + 0 --> x").  You'll necessarily have a finite set of these.  Then implement each one without tangling it with the others; otherwise you'll drown in the complexity of a if statements like you have.   That scheme might not be efficient; for that you need a rule compiler (which you have attempted to do badly by hand).   Building a mechanical rule compiler into a simplifier is a lot more effective than doing it by hand.

Comment: improved formatting.